# How can I use modernuiicons in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, modern-ui

i want to use the modern ui icons (modernuiicons.com) in WPF. Somehow I really get confused with all the WPF stuff. What I've tried to do is:

1. Merge all XAML files into one file
2. Wrap it into a ResourceDictionary

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
       <Canvas x:Name="appbar_acorn" Width="48" Height="48" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 48,0L 48,48L 0,48L 0,0">
           <Path Width="22.3248" Height="25.8518" Canvas.Left="13.6757" Canvas.Top="11.4012" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 16.6309,18.6563C 17.1309,8.15625 29.8809,14.1563 29.8809,14.1563C 30.8809,11.1563 34.1308,11.4063 34.1308,11.4063C 33.5,12 34.6309,13.1563 34.6309,13.1563C 32.1309,13.1562 31.1309,14.9062 31.1309,14.9062C 41.1309,23.9062 32.6309,27.9063 32.6309,27.9062C 24.6309,24.9063 21.1309,22.1562 16.6309,18.6563 Z M 16.6309,19.9063C 21.6309,24.1563 25.1309,26.1562 31.6309,28.6562C 31.6309,28.6562 26.3809,39.1562 18.3809,36.1563C 18.3809,36.1563 18,38 16.3809,36.9063C 15,36 16.3809,34.9063 16.3809,34.9063C 16.3809,34.9063 10.1309,30.9062 16.6309,19.9063 Z "/>
       </Canvas>
       <Canvas x:Name="appbar_add" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
           <Path Width="38" Height="38" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="19" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 35,19L 41,19L 41,35L 57,35L 57,41L 41,41L 41,57L 35,57L 35,41L 19,41L 19,35L 35,35L 35,19 Z "/>
       </Canvas>
       <Canvas x:Name="appbar_adobe_acrobat" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
           <Path Width="40.9131" Height="42.7219" Canvas.Left="19.254" Canvas.Top="16.6412" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 27.7221,48.2991C 22.1667,50.6667 21.4941,56.8336 22.766,55.4523C 30.2426,47.0743 34.4269,40.2614 36.76,35.125C 31.6002,25.9387 31.8796,14.635 37.9093,16.9458C 42.5866,18.7382 40.3545,23.0832 40.3545,23.0832C 40.3545,23.0832 39.7309,17.771 36.8125,18.6042C 36.116,18.7783 35.2582,25.4654 38.0971,31.8382C 40.0108,26.4778 39.6257,23.694 39.6257,23.694C 39.6257,23.694 44.4664,24.9554 40.0649,35.2833C 40.6006,36.0286 41.2037,36.7499 41.8815,37.4343C 42.8865,38.5858 43.894,39.5811 44.8903,40.4409C 47.8562,39.3684 50.7859,38.5921 53.0717,38.5921C 60.3583,38.5921 60.1667,45.9167 60.1667,45.9167C 58.5426,42.2264 53.5996,41.9021 48.2032,42.8653C 54.5071,46.7006 59.6426,45.6317 59.6426,45.6317C 59.106,50.0635 52.0743,50.4677 44.1396,43.7901C 39.8148,44.9614 35.6532,46.619 33.0903,47.7215C 26.4927,57.8007 20.6758,62.7377 19.4259,56.8004C 17.8425,49.2796 27.7221,48.2991 27.7221,48.2991 Z M 39.7906,39.4675L 38.7217,38.1415L 37.6342,40.1754C 36.7219,41.8103 35.8082,43.3751 34.9025,44.8555C 36.7884,43.9056 39.2316,42.725 41.8117,41.6458C 41.1395,40.9716 40.4646,40.2461 39.7906,39.4675 Z "/>
       </Canvas>
       <Canvas x:Name="appbar_adobe_aftereffects" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
           <Path Width="48.4387" Height="30.581" Canvas.Left="14.2799" Canvas.Top="22.2925" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 23.9216,22.2925L 30.9309,22.2925L 40.7089,52.3818L 34.8148,52.3818L 32.0925,43.8554L 22.5386,43.8554L 19.949,52.3818L 14.2799,52.3818L 23.9216,22.2925 Z M 25.7526,32.2927L 23.4316,39.7038L 31.1545,39.7038L 28.7885,32.2927C 28.2077,30.4626 27.7169,28.4088 27.2706,26.6681L 27.1815,26.6681C 26.7348,28.4088 26.288,30.5071 25.7526,32.2927 Z M 42.7186,41.8462C 42.7186,35.8199 46.3794,30.1499 53.3437,30.1499C 60.4412,30.1499 62.7186,35.954 62.7186,40.7305C 62.7186,41.7567 62.6295,42.5606 62.5399,43.0515L 47.9868,43.0515C 48.1204,46.9808 51.2004,48.676 54.6826,48.676C 57.2272,48.676 59.0578,48.3202 60.7098,47.6948L 61.5133,51.4897C 59.6381,52.2477 57.0495,52.8735 53.9232,52.8735C 46.8702,52.8735 42.7186,48.4979 42.7186,41.8462 Z M 53.031,33.9002C 49.6379,33.9002 48.209,36.9802 47.9868,39.2121L 57.5403,39.2121C 57.5848,37.2038 56.6913,33.9002 53.031,33.9002 Z "/>
       </Canvas>
       <Canvas x:Name="appbar_adobe_audition" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
           <Path Width="49.026" Height="30.5803" Canvas.Left="13.2674" Canvas.Top="22.442" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 22.9113,22.442L 29.9198,22.442L 39.6964,52.5309L 33.8046,52.5309L 31.0801,44.0041L 21.5274,44.0041L 18.9374,52.5309L 13.2674,52.5309L 22.9113,22.442 Z M 24.7419,32.4413L 22.4196,39.8524L 30.1429,39.8524L 27.7769,32.4413C 27.1961,30.6112 26.7057,28.5578 26.259,26.8172L 26.1699,26.8172C 25.7236,28.5578 25.2773,30.6566 24.7419,32.4413 Z M 56.6229,30.7902L 62.1152,30.7902L 62.1152,46.0129C 62.1152,48.6033 62.2034,50.7453 62.2934,52.5309L 57.4723,52.5309L 57.2042,49.2273L 57.1147,49.2273C 56.1771,50.7903 54.0342,53.0222 50.1503,53.0222C 46.1773,53.0222 42.5605,50.6562 42.5605,43.5587L 42.5605,30.7902L 48.052,30.7902L 48.052,42.6206C 48.052,46.2364 49.2122,48.5575 52.1145,48.5575C 54.3019,48.5575 55.7303,46.9963 56.3107,45.6115C 56.4893,45.1198 56.6229,44.5399 56.6229,43.9145L 56.6229,30.7902 Z "/>
       </Canvas>
       <Canvas x:Name="appbar_adobe_bridge" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
           <Path Width="37.6799" Height="30.6256" Canvas.Left="21.2627" Canvas.Top="21.9519" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 21.2627,22.5768C 23.0038,22.22 26.1733,21.9519 29.2537,21.9519C 33.3163,21.9519 35.8163,22.4432 37.8692,23.872C 39.7452,24.9873 40.995,26.952 40.995,29.4966C 40.995,32.2643 39.2544,34.8089 35.9945,36.0142L 35.9945,36.1042C 39.1644,36.9077 42.0667,39.4078 42.0667,43.5598C 42.0667,46.2376 40.9055,48.3363 39.1644,49.7643C 37.0216,51.6395 33.4949,52.5775 28.0035,52.5775C 24.9676,52.5775 22.647,52.3534 21.2627,52.1757L 21.2627,22.5768 Z M 26.7087,26.238L 26.7087,34.4522L 29.5214,34.4522C 33.3163,34.4522 35.4591,32.6661 35.4591,30.122C 35.4591,27.3088 33.3163,26.0144 29.8345,26.0144C 28.2271,26.0144 27.2899,26.1035 26.7087,26.238 Z M 26.7087,48.2913C 27.424,48.4254 28.3616,48.4254 29.6109,48.4254C 33.1381,48.4254 36.2621,47.0865 36.2621,43.3808C 36.2621,39.8986 33.2276,38.4702 29.4323,38.4702L 26.7087,38.4702L 26.7087,48.2913 Z M 51.7097,34.6749C 52.7813,31.5949 55.325,30.0324 57.6478,30.0324L 58.9426,30.166L 58.9426,35.3448C 58.4954,35.2557 58.0046,35.1666 57.3342,35.1666C 54.7006,35.1666 52.9154,36.8627 52.4237,39.3178L 52.2455,41.0148L 52.2455,52.2648L 46.755,52.2648L 46.755,37.5326C 46.755,34.5862 46.7091,32.4875 46.5751,30.5237L 51.3524,30.5237L 51.5311,34.6749L 51.7097,34.6749 Z "/>
       </Canvas>
       <Canvas x:Name="appbar_adobe_dreamweaver" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
           <Path Width="50.9949" Height="29.9759" Canvas.Left="13.8031" Canvas.Top="22.3452" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 13.8031,22.9571C 15.9392,22.5638 18.6692,22.3452 21.5566,22.3452C 26.5401,22.3452 29.9822,23.4812 32.4337,25.7536C 35.0053,28.0701 36.5875,31.5653 36.5875,36.5911C 36.5875,41.8337 34.9652,45.7662 32.4337,48.3009C 29.7838,50.9669 25.5512,52.3211 20.3693,52.3211C 17.5215,52.3211 15.385,52.1465 13.8031,51.9279L 13.8031,22.9571 Z M 21.3586,48.039L 21.4662,48.0395C 27.7309,48.0399 31.4448,44.1956 31.4448,36.7656C 31.4844,30.2548 28.0827,26.5405 21.9916,26.5405C 20.4485,26.5405 19.3409,26.6714 18.6692,26.8464L 18.6692,47.9081C 19.3409,48.039 20.3693,48.039 21.3586,48.039 Z M 60.161,30.7348L 64.7981,30.7348L 58.9337,52.0152L 54.5643,52.0152L 52.341,43.3637C 51.7674,41.135 51.3449,39.1249 50.9234,36.5461L 50.8455,36.5461C 50.4631,39.1689 49.9646,41.2659 49.4284,43.3637L 47.0516,52.0152L 42.644,52.0152L 37.1251,30.7348L 41.9547,30.7348L 43.9091,40.3922L 45.0964,47.2963L 45.1737,47.2963C 45.557,44.9798 46.1702,42.6205 46.707,40.4363L 49.1211,30.7348L 52.9546,30.7348L 55.2923,40.1736L 56.7873,47.2963L 56.8642,47.2963C 57.1701,44.9798 57.5926,42.6642 58.0906,40.1736L 60.161,30.7348 Z "/>
       </Canvas>
       ...
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```

   Now I've got an error, that every dictionary item must have an associated key.
3. I thought no problem, just replace `x:Name` with `x:Key`.

   But this isn't working either, because some of them depend on other ones. For example this one:

   ```
   <Canvas x:Name="appbar_base" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
       <Path x:Name="Base_Circle" Width="74.4167" Height="74.4167" Canvas.Left="0.791662" Canvas.Top="0.791664" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 38,0.791664C 58.5496,0.791664 75.2083,17.4504 75.2083,38C 75.2083,58.5496 58.5496,75.2083 38,75.2083C 17.4504,75.2083 0.791662,58.5496 0.791662,38C 0.791662,17.4504 17.4504,0.791664 38,0.791664 Z M 38,5.54166C 20.0738,5.54166 5.54167,20.0738 5.54167,38C 5.54167,55.9262 20.0738,70.4583 38,70.4583C 55.9262,70.4583 70.4583,55.9262 70.4583,38C 70.4583,20.0738 55.9262,5.54166 38,5.54166 Z "/>
   </Canvas>
   ```

How do I get this stuff to work?
Thank you.

Comment: Here's another great collection of modern icons free of charge : http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio. You can export them to PNG or even get the original XAML geometry.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, the `Canvas` is not required, accordingly as properties `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` for Path. As far as I know, it automatically adds the application (e.g. Blend), which generates these Path's.

Most importantly it is *`Data`* at object Path. You need to do the following:

In Resources `App.xaml`, `<Window.Resources>`, etc. add Path with key:

```
<Path x:Key="MyPath" Data="F1 M 0,0L ..." />
```

And in `Style` or where else use like this:

```
<Path x:Name="MyPathButton"
      ...
      Fill="{StaticResource ButtonBackground}" 
      Data="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyPath}, Path=Data}" />
```

It should be remembered here that for Path is required set such properties as:

- Stretch
- Width
- Height
- Fill aka Background

Can this be done on the resources side, but I think that it is better to set them in the place of use, because one `Path` (figure) can be used in different places.